# How to populate two columns from vector function that return a tuple (col_a, col_b)

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

The below throws an error

```
def test(throwaway):
    return(1,2)

df['prices_study'], df['prices_bench'] = list(map(dates_ok, df.date_announce))
```

I understand I can just create each column seperately but surely there's a way to condense this?

Comment: What is `test` doing here? Nothing, evidently. Could you please also provide some sample data to work with? 3-5 rows is enough.

Comment: What that guy said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Use a splat to unpack the `map` object within a `zip`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(4), [*'abc'])

def test(_): return (2, 3)

df['d'], df['e'] = zip(*map(test, df.index))

df

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  2  3
1  1  1  1  2  3
2  1  1  1  2  3
3  1  1  1  2  3
```